# How to fix a Tomcat that remains in 'activating' when attempting to start it as a service on Ubuntu

Tags: digital-ocean, systemd, ubuntu-18.04, tomcat9, systemctl

I'm having an issue to run Tomcat as a service on an Ubuntu 18.04 droplet.

What is even more weird is that I have 2 droplets. On one of them, it works like a charm.
On the other, I know that Tomcat is properly set up because if I run myself /bin/tomcat/bin/startup.sh, the server starts instantly and I can successfully access it.

However, when I use the script recommanded in this tutorial (step 5):
[digital ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/install-tomcat-9-ubuntu-1804#step-7%E2%80%94-configure-tomcat-web-management-interface)

The tomcat server is unable to start. It keeps getting stuck when activating the service:

> ● tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
>      Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
>     Active: activating (auto-restart) since Mon 2018-12-31 09:48:40 UTC; 3s ago
>     Process: 4035 ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>     Process: 4016 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
>    Main PID: 4031 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

I also ready somewhere that adding the following JAVA_OPT in the tomcat service script file would help... but it didn't in my case.

> -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom

Does anybody have any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this problem? I'm having the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered the same issue. Fixed it by installing java on my droplet.

```
apt update 
apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```